# Issue in validating default email domain email address

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to make a email form field to accept only default domain.

However, if i enter invalid email domain i get the error as expected.

if i enter the valid email address first, it works fine. But if i enter an invalid email and later change it to valid email, the error still shows

Below is the code from component

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" >
   <input matInput type="email" placeholder="name@desoz.com" formControlName="userEmail">
   <mat-error *ngIf="createUserForm.controls.userEmail.errors.pattern" >
      User email domain should be @desoz.com
   </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

component code

```
ngOnInit(){

this.createUserForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      userEmail: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.email,
        Validators.pattern(/[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-,;]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.,;)?[a-zA-Z]+\.,;)?(desoz)\.com/)
        ]
      ]
   })
}
```

When i provide a valid email address i get an error in the console

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pattern' of null

Please let me know how i can resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issues stem from:

```html
<mat-error *ngIf="createUserForm.controls.userEmail.errors.pattern" >
```

If the email is in fact valid according to all validators, there is no such property like `errors` and therefore throws an error about that. This also then messes with your validation.

I would suggest you start using [`hasError`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#haserror) instead, to avoid such issues. You could also use the safe navigation operator on the above code like `errors?.pattern`, but I prefer `hasError`:

```html
<mat-error *ngIf="createUserForm.hasError('pattern', 'userEmail')">
```

Then your code seems to work just fine:

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9k5qp-p8dvkm?file=app/input-overview-example.html)**

Comment: This works fine if i set a default email domain. I am trying to set dynamic data coming from the API as default for pattern. I get error when i set a string like expression. eg..: Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-,;]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.,;)?[a-zA-Z]+\\.,;)?('+this.clientDomain+')\\.'+this.postDomain+'')

Comment: well your question does not say anything about it, so my answer would apply to your question. please fork my stackblitz with this new issue and I'd be happy to see if I can help further.